# Когда корректно использовать flex, когда float, а когда inline-block?

Tags: вёрстка

Можно ли полностью отказаться от использования `float` и `inline-block` и перейти полностью на `flex`?

Когда корректно использовать одно, а когда другое?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Отказаться можно от чего угодно, вопрос только, зачем.

Во-первых, видимо имеется в виду не прямое предназначение этих возможностей (которое совершенно разное), а их использование для вёрстки некого лейаута.

У каждого способа есть свои плюсы и минусы. Flexbox не разрабатывался для лейаутов - он достаточно гибкий и удобный, но имеет определённое сходство с таблицами, снижает управляемость и увеличивает время обработки. Использовать его для сложных блоков со множеством элементов (например, лейаута всей страницы) не рекомендуется. Впрочем, я не проверял эту информацию.

Для лейаутов предназначены гридовые сетки (display: grid). Однако, браузеры их до сих пор не поддерживают. Ждём.

Inline-блоки решают проблемы вертикального выравнивания и обеспечения строк элементов. Удобно, когда нужно разместить строками элементы разной высоты. Заодно создают проблемы с пробелами между ними.

Float часто используется для колонок и боковых панелей. Вызывает необходимость использования clearfix'а.

PS: Ещё раз подчеркну, что описанное не является использованием этих возможностей по прямому назначению.

Comment: С моей скромной практикой layout c использованием flex'ов на скорость не влияют. А вот кроссбраузерность пока что хромает. Особенно для Safari, которые всячески навязывают браузерные префиксы. Про IE думаю говорить не стоит даже. Но если знаешь, у какого браузера слабое место, то багом легко избежать.

Comment: @NeedHate, с кроссбраузерностью вроде всё вполне приемлемо. Хотя про сафари не скажу - маков нет.